# Change active border color from React Navigation - MaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, styling, react-navigation-v5

There is a default blue bottom-border on the active tab. But I can't change this border-color.
Can somebody tell me how to change this default color ?

```js
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const SpecificChannelNavigator = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator 
    tabBarOptions={{
      style: {
        // borderColor: colors['color-primary-500'],
        borderColor: "transparant"
      }
    }}
  >
    <Tab.Screen name={Routes.groupChat} component={GroupChat} />
    <Tab.Screen name={Routes.users} component={Users} />
    <Tab.Screen name={Routes.groupChatSettings} component={ChannelSettings} />
  </Tab.Navigator> 
);

export default SpecificChannelNavigator;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the indicatorStyle prop like this:

```
TabBarOptions={{
      indicatorStyle:{backgroundColor: color}
    }}
```